# Requests to malicious IP being sent by background process on Windows

Tags: windows, security, tor, malware

Whenever an internet connection is established on my pc, I am repeatedly getting warnings from QuickHeal like this:
[QuckhealWarning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54RcH.png)
I am getting such warnings repeatedly with different IP addresses. In the above image one of them is shown. These warnings appear even just after startup when no apps are open except the ones that start at startup.

I decided to investigate and here are some of my observations:

1. A reverse DNS lookup of the IP addresses revealed that the domain name for most of them is of the form "torNN.quintex.com" where NN is a number like 48 or 90 (different for different IP addresses against which warnings were received)
2. I tried to track the process which established the connection using the "netstat -ano" command and found their PIDs. Then I tried to kill the processes with the PID but it showed that the process doesn't exist. On observing a bit more I noticed that the processes making the connections were terminating instantaneously. My guess is that some other process is spawning these processes that are sending the request and terminating. So I tried to find the ParentPIDs using "netstat -ano && wmic process get ProcessID,ParentProcessID", but even then, the PIDs found by the first command didn't show up in the second one, probably because the processes terminated before their PPIDs could be captured by the second command.

The behavior of these processes and the presence of "tor" in the domain name and url path lead me to the conclusion that this might be because of some malware and I am quite worried about it. I also saw a high fraud risk score [here](https://scamalytics.com/ip/199.249.230.182). But I don't know how to get rid of it and am still unable to find the process that is spawning the other instantaneously terminating processes.

Can someone please guide me on how to find the cause and get rid of it ?

Platform: Windows 11

Comment: Though I can not help here, I appreciate the question. Interesting case you have there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do. Use an app that catches all IP traffic and something that can see what ports are being used and use your firewall close them down. I would shut them all down and open them one by one eg. starting with port 80. If its coming though port 80 then you monitor all traffic through that port. The bad one is sure to be trapped that way. Eventualy you will find the port where the traffic is coming from and along with it maybe some  ipaddresses. Your firewall should be able to block that ip range.
You can also try netstat -a -n 2 > mylog.txt or other netstat options to get a log going. Run netstat -a -n 2 > mylog.txt for a while and the ctrl-c and then : type mylog.txt and you will see all traffic per second.

Comment: netstat -ano also shows ports. I observed that the ports above 50000 are being used. But one specific port is not being used all the time, it's varying, and I dont know if blocking all ports above 50000 will harm the working of any other apps... Same for the ip address, it's not always happening from same IP, there are a lot of different ones, but most of them have domain names of form torNN.quintex.com. I cant quite get a list of all the IPs against which I'm getting warnings as the process is happening too fast...